# VB.NET USB to Parallel programming

Tags: vb.net, parallel-port

Before I was working on PC that had integrated Parallel port, but now I have laptop computer and I bought USB to Parallel port converter hoping that I can work on application that will communicate with Data pins of that Parallel port...

Can this converter be used as regular integrated parallel port?

I checked pins and all data out pins have signals all the time...

I tried with **inpout32.dll** scripts that I used for my PC ( that works 100% ) but it doesn't look to work on laptop...

Does programming has to be different when it uses converters like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From computer to computer, the IO address used for the Parallel port can vary. This page has a good explanation of how to find the port address for the computer. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20545/I-O-Ports-Programming-Parallel-port-Reading-Writin

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I found out that it's not the same this way, so I can't use this converter... I started learning about USB, since most of the newer computers doesn't have parallel port, so anything made with that will be almost useless... But thank you for you answer.